Power BI - drill down on line chart
I have a table such as below in Power BI. I want to create a line chart that drills Animal-> Subcategory. I have Date in the x axis, Value in the y-axis and Animal in the legend field. I can add another field to the legend field. Does anybody know how I can do that?
I also have an Animal filter at the top, when selecting an animal, it would be nice if the chart would automatically update to show the subcategory



Date
Animal
Subcategory
Value




2024-01
Cat
Siamese
100


2024-01
Cat
Persian
150


2024-01
Dog
Bulldog
200


2024-01
Dog
Beagle
250


2024-01
Bird
Parrot
300


2024-02
Bird
Sparrow
350




This can be done using a Field Parameter. It will need to be enabled before it can be used. Steps to enable it can be found here.
Create a new Field Parameter and add Animal and Subcategory to it.

Add this new Field Parameter to the Legend of your visual. Use the autogenerated slicer to switch between Animal and Subcategory.

Subcategory Selected:


Thanks so much! Really useful, especially since it can also replace bookmarks in some instances.
